# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, dell

**The issue:**

I'm using a Dell XPS 13 9370, bought just last November. It was working fine with Ubuntu 18.04 until last night.

I'm now unable to connect to Wi-Fi at all. In "Settings" under "Wi-Fi" I just see "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". There's no wireless icon in the top bar either. Furthermore, in BIOS under "System Information", the "Wi-Fi Device" now just shows as "(none)".

I've searched around for those with similar issues and haven't had luck yet.

**What I've tried:**

- I used a bootable USB to "Try Ubuntu" and the issue was the same there (so, that would indicate that a clean install is not the solution)
- `sudo lshw -class network` gives a totally blank output
- `sudo rfkill list` just shows my bluetooth, no wireless
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bmwcl-kernel-source` didn't work

The laptop is new, and apparently the Wi-Fi card is soldered on, so it would be very disappointing if this is a hardware issue and I'm hoping to determine that's not the case. I didn't drop it or anything, though when the problem started I was running heavy code and the fans were quite loud.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I would run `hardinfo` from the apt repo It displays a browser to examine your hardware. Another thing I'd try is to plug in a USB wifi adapter - inexpensive and easily acquired at electronics outlets. There are no doubt more sophisticated diagnostic tools and people will weigh in with those but I'd give these a try. If you have damaged your wifi card a good USB 3.0 adapter gives fairly acceptable performance. I have a couple of old laptops rescued by these little dongles. So if you're out of warranty you'll be okay.

Comment: @StephenBoston I ran hardinfo and it's not listing any wireless device there either. At the very least, I'm currently tethering my phone for the wifi and that's working alright, but I'll definitely look into a USB adapter for the long term. Thanks for the advice!